# Mobclix and Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, ads, mobclix

I'm trying to use Proguard to obfuscate my code. I use Mobclix for advertisements, and when I build my APK it's spitting out an error:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:228)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:290)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:229)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: Proguard Error 1 
Output: 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsCursorEntityIterator: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsCursorEntityIterator: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5$EntityIteratorImpl: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5$EntityIteratorImpl: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5$EntityIteratorImpl: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5$EntityIteratorImpl: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5$EntityIteratorImpl: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsEntityIterator: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity$NamedContentValues 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity$NamedContentValues 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity$NamedContentValues 
Warning: com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsSdk5: can't find referenced class android.content.Entity 
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars. 
Warning: there were 17 unresolved references to classes or interfaces. 
         You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'), 
         or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option. 
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. 
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:308) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:210) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:85) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.runProguard(BuildHelper.java:527)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:187)
    ... 4 more
```

Now, I have put the Mobclix recommended bits from their documentation into my proguard.cfg:

```
-keep public class com.mobclix.android.sdk.*
-keep class com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixJavascriptInterface

-keepclassmembers class com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixJavascriptInterface
{
    public void *(...);
    <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembernames class
com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixJavascriptInterface {
    public void *(...);
    <methods>;
}
```

Anything else I should be doing? Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages explain that some Mobclix classes (like `com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixContactsCursorEntityIterator`) depend on Android runtime classes (like `android.content.Entity`) that are not present in your input jars or library jars. In general, that could be a sign of serious problems: if that part of the code is ever executed, it will fail with NoClassDefFoundError (even without obfuscation).

It looks like the Entity class has been introduced in Android SDK 7, so I presume that you are building against an older SDK. Again assuming that your code runs fine in spite of this missing class, you can let ProGuard accept the somewhat inconsistent input with

```
-dontwarn android.content.Entity*
```

Note that -keep options don't come into play here. ProGuard performs the consistency checks before considering any -keep options.

Also see [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/index.html) > Troubleshooting > Warning: can't find referenced class

Comment: Excellent answer. I am indeed building against SDK 4, but targeting 7. It's been working without any problems for 15 versions, but if I do run into a NoClassDefFoundError I guess I'll know what to look into. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change

```
-keep public class com.mobclix.android.sdk.*
```

to

```
-keep public class com.mobclix.android.sdk.**
```

Comment: maybe add `-keep public class android.content.Entity`, and never delete the default stuff in the `proguard.cfg` generated in a new eclipse project, so if you deleted that, then create a new project and copy that `proguard.cfg` code

Comment: Hmmm. I haven't looked at the mobclix SDK, so I'm not sure if I can help you, try deleting everything after `-keep public class com.mobclix.android.sdk.**` relating to mobclix.